# pack stuff other than target/classes with maven jar

Tags: maven-2, jar

I am using maven jar plugin to package the jar file. But it looks like maven jar plugin just only pack the stuff that stay inside target/classes. I am also want to pack all the classes in target/classes and (resource and class) files from many other directories. How can i do that with maven jar?

Comment: `I am also want to pack all the classes in target/classes and (resource and class) files from many other directories.` Before answering, I'd really like to understand from where these other files are coming from? Why don't they actually end up in `target/classes`? I have the feeling that you are bending Maven and there might be a better way. Please add some details.

Comment: thanks. Pascal. The resource files stays in another folder of project. The other classes are generated classes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The resource files stays in another folder of project.

If you can't (or just don't want to) put them under `src/main/resources`, you can declare additional resource locations using the `<resource>` element:

```
<project>
 ...
 <build>
   ...
   <resources>
     <resource>
       <directory> [your folder here] </directory>
     </resource>
   </resources>
   ...
 </build>
 ...
</project>
```

See [Specifying resource directories](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/resource-directory.html).

> The other classes are generated classes.

The convention with plugins generating *sources* it to generate them in `target/generated-sources/<tool>` and a well implemented plugin **should** add the specified path as a source directory (so that generated code would be compiled). When they don't, the [Build Helper Maven Plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/build-helper-maven-plugin/) can come to the rescue.

If you are generating *classes*, why don't you generate them in `${project.build.outputDirectory}` (i.e. `target/classes` by default)? I don't think you can add a 2nd classes directory anyway.

If this doesn't help, please clarify your exact constraints and requirements.

#### References

- [Specifying resource directories](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/resource-directory.html)
- [MavenPropertiesGuide](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/MAVENUSER/MavenPropertiesGuide)

Comment: Thanks Pascal. I will try Build Helper Maven Plugin and <resource>. :-)